# What's wrong with strtol?

Tags: c

I have this code, which should run fine, but for some reason, the loop would cycle through when I free the string before the conditional check of the loop. And the only way to get out from the loop is by giving integer with more than 3 digits (input > 99 || input < -99).
I'm using gcc to compile this code with code::blocks as IDE.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* createString(void);

int main() {

  int temp = 0;
  char* string = 0;
  char* error = 0;

  do {
    printf("\n  Integer: ");
    string = createString();
    temp = strtol(string, &error, 10);
    if (*error != '\n' && *error != '\0') printf("\n  Input is not an integer");
    free(string);
    string = 0;
  } while (*error != '\n' && *error != '\0');
  free(error);
  error = 0;
  return 0;
}

char* createString() {

  char* string = 0;
  size_t size = 0;
  size_t index = 0;
  int ch = EOF;

  do {
    ch = getc(stdin);
    if (ch == EOF || ch == '\n') ch = 0;
    if (size <= index) string = (char*) realloc(string, size += 5);
    if (!string) {
      perror("realloc");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    string[index++] = ch;
  } while(ch);
  return string;
}
```

I did a work-around it by moving the free-ing process to the beginning of the loop cycle and after the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* createString(void);

int main() {

  int temp = 0;
  char* string = 0;
  char* error = 0;

  do {
    free(string);
    string = 0;
    printf("\n  Integer: ");
    string = createString();
    temp = strtol(string, &error, 10);
    if (*error != '\n' && *error != '\0') printf("\n  Input is not an integer");
  } while (*error != '\n' && *error != '\0');
  free(string);
  string = 0;
  free(error);
  error = 0;
  return 0;
}

char* createString() {

  char* string = 0;
  size_t size = 0;
  size_t index = 0;
  int ch = EOF;

  do {
    ch = getc(stdin);
    if (ch == EOF || ch == '\n') ch = 0;
    if (size <= index) string = (char*) realloc(string, size += 5);
    if (!string) {
      perror("realloc");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    string[index++] = ch;
  } while(ch);
  return string;
}
```

The code works fine now, but I'm wondering what is strtol doing.

Comment: ...and it would be **so** much easier for everyone if **you** had done the work of reducing this to an example that **only** does the `strtol` part you find confusing. (If it even **is** `strtol` that is giving you trouble, and you're not working on faulty assumptions somewhere else in your code.) At this point I'll downvote the question and not even *bother* to find which source line you're even referring to. (This is called "debugging", by the way, and you should do it *before* posting to the 'net about your code.)

Comment: what's wrong with `std::string`, `std::getline` and `std::stol`

Comment: That it's C++ only. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
free(error);
```

Remove it. `error` is not allocated in `strtol` or anywhere else. It is a pointer that points to the middle of `string`.  Freeing it is UB.

Comment: @user3163916 Eh? You didn't know that you can't free a pointer to something you didn't malloc/realloc?

Comment: @JimBalter I didn't know how `strtol` store values into error. I was under the assumption that `strtol` scans through the `string` and dump the exception on `error` via memory allocation.

Comment: @user3163916 Well that's a mighty weird assumption. Nowhere does the strtol doc say anything about allocating memory; it quite clearly says that the endptr (not error) is set to point to the char that wasn't parsed. And if it did allocate memory, you would be leaking it, as you only do the free outside the loop.

Answer (score 5):

You say:

> for some reason, the loop would cycle through when I free the string before the conditional check of the loop

Keep in mind that with the call `strtol(string, &error, 10);` the pointer `error` will point into the string `string`.  So if you free `string` before doing this:

```
if (*error != '\n' && *error != '\0') printf("\n  Input is not an integer");
```

or this:

```
 while (*error != '\n' && *error != '\0')
```

You'll invoke undefined behavior because `error` will be pointing to freed memory.

Comment: Thanks, I had a misconception about the behavior of strtol.

Comment: @user3163916: Which means you *used* a function without referring to its documentation first, then found its behaviour confusing, and still didn't read its documentation thoroughly before posting to a Q&A site? There's a lesson in there...

Comment: @DevSolar I'm having trouble at locating documentation with throughout explanation about the behavior of strtol. I've found plenty C++ references, but those aren't the one that I'm looking. Would you kindly refer me to the documentation that you mentioned? Thank you.

Comment: @Evert and user3163916: I personally prefer man7.org over linux.die.net (it seems to be better maintained, and I find it easier on the eyes).  See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html

Comment: @MichaelBurr Michael, thanks. I just linked the first Google hit, which may indeed not be the best. And in practice, I just enter `man strtol` om the command line. But I'll keep `man7.org` in my head as well.

Comment: @user3163916: Others have pointed you to online manpages as well as command-line versions. Personally, I actually prefer using [the language standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) directly, as it is very precisely worded, and I found Linux manpages less than clear about what's ISO/IEC standard, what's POSIX, and what's Linux-specific. The difference matters when you're aiming for certain levels of portability. For things beyond the language standard, by all means use `man` pages.

Comment: @DevSolar Thank you for the link. I've read into it, and I have a bit uncertainty concerning paragraph 5 last line of **7.22.1.4** (apologize, I don't know how to link to the page, so I'll leave the quote it):  `A pointer to the ﬁnal string is stored in the
object pointed to by endptr, provided that endptr is not a null pointer` Not sure if I'm getting it right, but does that line mean: `if(*endptr != '\0') *endptr == str[last]`?

Comment: @user3163916 "I'm having trouble at locating documentation with throughout explanation about the behavior of strtol" -- this isn't about strtol, it's about free ... you can't just hand pointers to free willy-nilly.

Comment: @user3163916 "does that line mean ..." -- no, it's more like `if(*endptr != NULL) *endptr = str+last`

Comment: @user3163916: The idea is that you could call `strtol( str, NULL, base )` -- i.e. not *having* to provide a variable in which `strtol()` would store the end pointer in, because you might not be interested in that value.

Comment: @JimBalter Ah, thanks for the clarifications. I'm learning much faster this way.

Comment: @user3163916 Oops, that should have been `if(endptr != NULL) *endptr = str+last`. And reading the manual, carefully, is far faster for all concerned.